# How to add same sprite in cocos2D?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sprite

I have sprite "brick" that I want to use many times in my parallax background.
Is there a way that I can reuse that same sprite?
Because I have to set collision detection too for my sprite...
If I use too many variable, I think that's useless.
Thanks for the help

Comment: CCSpriteBatchNode will render all its children sprites in the same draw calls, but are you actually wanting 1 object in memory that is displayed multiple times on the screen? I don't know that this is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not re-use the same instance of a CCSprite. You can however re-use the texture, which Cocos2D does automatically for you.

You can create multiple sprites using the same image file or sprite frame. For example this will create 100 brick sprites and give each a unique tag from 0 to 99:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   CCSprite* brick = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"brick.png"];
   [self addChild:brick z:0 tag:i];
}
```

All sprites using the image file "brick.png" will use the same in-memory texture. CCTextureCache caches each loaded image file so that the additional memory usage for each CCSprite is close to 500 Bytes (I checked that once with the Objective-C runtime). That means a thousand sprites using the same texture will use about 500 KB plus the amount of memory the texture uses.

Comment: CCSprite* brick; 
i want to declare it as global variable(in *.h file)
is it possible(in the above context)?